# time comparison in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window

I don't know how to code a bat file for time comparing.

The bat file is to get current time and if the time now is 00:00 or after but before 7:00, bat file will sent a command to shutdown the computer, else, it will do nothing.

```
set "currentTime=%TIME%
set flag=false
if %currentTime% geq 07:00 if %currentTime% leq 00:45 set flag=true
if %flag%==true (
    shutdown -s
) else (
    shutdown -a
)
```

Please help, I'm a new hand, thanks.

Comment: `if %time::=% geq 004500.00 if %time::=% leq 070000.00 set flag=true`

Answer (score 1):

your code line

```
if %currentTime% geq 07:00 if %currentTime% leq 00:45 set flag=true
```

compares, as a string, the current time to "07:00" and then to "00:45" and if the current time is **later** than 07:00 **AND earlier** than 00:45, performs `shutdown -s`, otherwise perfoms `shutdown -a`.

Since a time *cannot* be both, then it will always follow the `else` path.

But the code is set up to perform shutdown regardless, so it can't "do nothing" as you claim.

Perhaps you ***want*** to shutdown before 07:00 but with different paramaters if it's before 00:45

```
if %currentTime% lss 07:00 (
 if %currentTime% leq 00:45 (
    shutdown -s
  ) else (
    shutdown -a
  )
)
```

That is `shutdown -s` before 00:45 and `shutdown -a` if later than 00:45 but before 07:00

Your next problem is that you don't tell us which tme-formt you use. It's possible to use 24-hour time or 12-hour time and it's possible to use a leading "0" on the hours, or replace that leading `0` with a <kbd>Space</kbd>

Without knowing what format you use, there are four possibilities for conversion or comparison. The above should work with 24-hour, leading 0's.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. 24-hour tme-formt will be utilized and I wanna shutdown the computer after 00:45 but after 07:00. It meas computer will shutdown at 00:45 to 7:00, operate at 7:01 - 00:44.

Comment: `if %currentTime% leq 07:00 if %currentTime% geq 00:45 shutdown -s` should do that - the *shutdown* parameter is up to you. This should compare the current time to the string `07:00` and if less than or equal to then it compares the time to `00:45` and if it's greater than or equal to *that* string, executes the `shotdown` else does nothing.